Were Bloodstains Removed from Yom Kippur Curtains and Walls Each Year?
We know the Kohen sprinkled blood on the curtain, floor, and wall in the Beit HaMikdash during the Avodah on Yom Kippur. After scores of years -- even centuries -- were each year's stains been cleansed after Yom Kippur, or did the curtains, floors, and walls remain stained by years and years of the sprinklings?
